# MVVCross 6.0 & Xamarin Android : Cant get my platform specific code to register

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I just started coding in MVVMCross (6.0) and I am not sure how the Setup.cs methods get called (since it doesn't seem to be working for me). I want to write some android specific services that I wrote in IntializeFirstChance of my Setup class; but it never gets called.

Is there a hook I am missing to allow the Setup.cs methods to get invoked ?

Comment: My mistake .. I did not change the SplashScreen to pass my Setup Class MvxSplashScreenActivit<Setup,App>

Comment: Put it in the answer and mark it as the answer

Comment: Yes, basically I need to pass my Setup class when extending from the MvxFormsSplashScreenActivity
Like so … (silly mistake)

public class SplashScreen : MvxFormsSplashScreenActivity<Setup, Core.App, FormsApp>